# camus-example work with kafka

Tags: hadoop, apache-kafka, hadoop2, camus

My usecase is I want to push Avro data from Kafka to HDFS. Camus seems to be right tool, however I am not able to make it work.
I am new to camus, trying to make camus-example work, 
https://github.com/linkedin/camus

Now I am trying to make camus-example work. However I am still facing issues.

Code Snippet for DummyLogKafkaProducerClient

```
package com.linkedin.camus.example.schemaregistry;

import java.util.Date;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Properties;
import java.util.Random;

import kafka.javaapi.producer.Producer;
import kafka.producer.KeyedMessage;
import kafka.producer.ProducerConfig;

import com.linkedin.camus.etl.kafka.coders.KafkaAvroMessageEncoder;
import com.linkedin.camus.example.records.DummyLog;

public class DummyLogKafkaProducerClient {


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Properties props = new Properties();

        props.put("metadata.broker.list", "localhost:6667");
        // props.put("serializer.class", "kafka.serializer.StringEncoder");
        // props.put("partitioner.class", "example.producer.SimplePartitioner");
        //props.put("request.required.acks", "1");

        ProducerConfig config = new ProducerConfig(props);

        Producer<String, byte[]> producer = new Producer<String, byte[]>(config);

        KafkaAvroMessageEncoder encoder = get_DUMMY_LOG_Encoder();

        for (int i = 0; i < 500; i++) {
            KeyedMessage<String, byte[]> data = new KeyedMessage<String, byte[]>("DUMMY_LOG", encoder.toBytes(getDummyLog()));
            producer.send(data);

        }
    }

    public static DummyLog getDummyLog() {
        Random random = new Random();
        DummyLog dummyLog = DummyLog.newBuilder().build();
        dummyLog.setId(random.nextLong());
        dummyLog.setLogTime(new Date().getTime());
        Map<CharSequence, CharSequence> machoStuff = new HashMap<CharSequence, CharSequence>();
        machoStuff.put("macho1", "abcd");
        machoStuff.put("macho2", "xyz");
        dummyLog.setMuchoStuff(machoStuff);
        return dummyLog;
    }

    public static KafkaAvroMessageEncoder get_DUMMY_LOG_Encoder() {
        KafkaAvroMessageEncoder encoder = new KafkaAvroMessageEncoder("DUMMY_LOG", null);
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put(KafkaAvroMessageEncoder.KAFKA_MESSAGE_CODER_SCHEMA_REGISTRY_CLASS, "com.linkedin.camus.example.schemaregistry.DummySchemaRegistry");
        encoder.init(props, "DUMMY_LOG");
        return encoder;

    }
}
```

I am also added Default no-arg constructor ot DummySchemaRegistry as it was giving instantiation Exception

```
package com.linkedin.camus.example.schemaregistry;

import org.apache.avro.Schema;
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;

import com.linkedin.camus.example.records.DummyLog;
import com.linkedin.camus.example.records.DummyLog2;
import com.linkedin.camus.schemaregistry.MemorySchemaRegistry;

/**
 * This is a little dummy registry that just uses a memory-backed schema registry to store two dummy Avro schemas. You
 * can use this with camus.properties
 */
public class DummySchemaRegistry extends MemorySchemaRegistry<Schema> {
    public DummySchemaRegistry(Configuration conf) {
        super();
        super.register("DUMMY_LOG", DummyLog.newBuilder().build().getSchema());
        super.register("DUMMY_LOG_2", DummyLog2.newBuilder().build()
                .getSchema());
    }
    public DummySchemaRegistry() {
        super();
        super.register("DUMMY_LOG", DummyLog.newBuilder().build().getSchema());
        super.register("DUMMY_LOG_2", DummyLog2.newBuilder().build().getSchema());
    }
}
```

Below Exception trace I am getting after running the Program

> Exception in thread "main"
>   com.linkedin.camus.coders.MessageEncoderException:
>   org.apache.avro.AvroRuntimeException:
>   org.apache.avro.AvroRuntimeException: Field id type:LONG pos:0 not set
>   and has no default value  at
>   com.linkedin.camus.etl.kafka.coders.KafkaAvroMessageEncoder.init(KafkaAvroMessageEncoder.java:55)
>     at
>   com.linkedin.camus.example.schemaregistry.DummyLogKafkaProducerClient.get_DUMMY_LOG_Encoder(DummyLogKafkaProducerClient.java:57)
>     at
>   com.linkedin.camus.example.schemaregistry.DummyLogKafkaProducerClient.main(DummyLogKafkaProducerClient.java:32)
>   Caused by: org.apache.avro.AvroRuntimeException:
>   org.apache.avro.AvroRuntimeException: Field id type:LONG pos:0 not set
>   and has no default value  at
>   com.linkedin.camus.example.records.DummyLog$Builder.build(DummyLog.java:214)
>     at
>   com.linkedin.camus.example.schemaregistry.DummySchemaRegistry.(DummySchemaRegistry.java:16)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native
>   Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:408)
>     at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:438)  at
>   com.linkedin.camus.etl.kafka.coders.KafkaAvroMessageEncoder.init(KafkaAvroMessageEncoder.java:52)
>     ... 2 more Caused by: org.apache.avro.AvroRuntimeException: Field id
>   type:LONG pos:0 not set and has no default value  at
>   org.apache.avro.data.RecordBuilderBase.defaultValue(RecordBuilderBase.java:151)
>     at
>   com.linkedin.camus.example.records.DummyLog$Builder.build(DummyLog.java:209)
>     ... 9 more

Answer (score 1):

I suppose camus expects the Avro schema to have default values. I had changed my dummyLog.avsc to following and recompile-

{
  "namespace": "com.linkedin.camus.example.records",
  "type": "record",
  "name": "DummyLog",
  "doc": "Logs for not so important stuff.",
  "fields": [
        {
            "name": "id", 
            "type": "int",
            "default": 0 
        },
        {
            "name": "logTime", 
            "type": "int",
            "default": 0
        }
    ]
}

Let me know if it works for you.

Thanks,
Ambarish

Answer (score 0):

You can default any String or Long field as follows

```
  {"type":"record","name":"CounterData","namespace":"org.avro.usage.tutorial","fields":[{"name":"word","type":["string","null"]},{"name":"count","type":["long","null"]}]}
```

Answer (score 0):

Camus doesn't assume the schema will have default values. I have recently used camus found the same issue. Actually the way it used in schema registry is not correct in default example. I have done some modification in Camus code you can check out https://github.com/chandanbansal/camus there are minor changes to make it work. 
They don't have decoder for Avro records. I have written that as well.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this issue because I was initializing the registry like so:

```
super.register("DUMMY_LOG_2", LogEvent.newBuilder().build().getSchema());
```

When I changed it to:

```
super.register("logEventAvro", LogEvent.SCHEMA$);
```

That got me passed the exception.

I also used [Garry's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32864280/317027) `com.linkedin.camus.etl.kafka.coders.AvroMessageDecoder`.

I also found this blog ([Alvin Jin's Notebook](http://alvincjin.blogspot.ca/2014/12/trouble-shooting-for-kafka-camus-example.html)) very useful.  It pinpoints every issue you could have with camus example and solves it!